# Why won't Trix editor mount in Vue component when running tests with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-component

I built a simple Vue component that wraps the Trix editor. I'm trying to write tests for it, but Trix doesn't seem to mount properly and isn't generating a toolbar element like it does in the browser. I'm using Jest test runner.

**TrixEdit.vue**

```
<template>
  <div ref="trix">
    <trix-editor></trix-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'trix'

export default {
  mounted() {
    let el = this.$refs.trix.getElementsByTagName('trix-editor')[0]
    // HACK: change the URL field in the link dialog to allow non-urls
    let toolbar = this.$refs.trix.getElementsByTagName('trix-toolbar')[0]
    toolbar.querySelector('[type=url]').type = 'text'

    // insert content
    el.editor.insertHTML(this.value)

    el.addEventListener('trix-change', e => {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.innerHTML)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

**TrixEdit.spec.js**

```
import { mount, shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import TrixEdit from '@/components/TrixEdit.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.config.ignoredElements = ['trix-editor']

describe('TrixEdit', () => {
  describe('value prop', () => {
    it('renders text when value is set', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(TrixEdit, {
        localVue,
        propsData: {
          value: 'This is a test'
        }
      })

      expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toEqual('This is a test')
    })
  })
})
```

The `expect()` fails with the following error

```
    Expected value to equal:
      "This is a test"
    Received:
      undefined

    at Object.toEqual (tests/unit/TrixEdit.spec.js:19:39)
```

Why is Trix not initializing in my test?

Comment: Can you share the problematic repo?

Comment: @hackape unfortunately it's private.

Comment: mocha unit test runs in nodejs runtime, while `trix` only works in browser runtime. That's why it fails to initialize in unit test.

Comment: @hackape this is Jest, not Mocha.

Comment: well, mocha or jest, the problem is the same, runtime difference

Comment: @hackape right but trix has its own tests that mount, there are plenty of vue wrappers around trix that have tests, etc. I'm trying to determine the difference between my component and theirs.

Comment: What's the error that gets thrown in your jest test? Is it just a failure on the test expect line? Or is a different error being thrown that fails the test before it gets to the test assertion?

Comment: @Msencenb the expect fails. I've updated my answer with the error message.

Comment: Does the test pass without your toolbar hack? Wondering if we can rule out your own toolbar hack code as the culprit of the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trix-editor` is not mounting mainly because `MutationObserver` is not supported in JSDOM 11, and [`attachToDocument`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument) was not used. There were several other bugs in the test described below.

[GitHub demo w/issues fixed](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/trix-editor-vue-jest)

---

#### Missing `MutationObserver` and `window.getSelection`

Vue CLI 3.7.0 uses JSDOM 11, which doesn't support `MutationObserver`, needed by the Custom Elements polyfill to trigger the [`connectedCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks). That lifecycle hook normally invokes `trix-editor`'s initialization, which would create the `trix-toolbar` element that your test is trying to query.

**Solution 1:** In your test, import [`mutationobserver-shim`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mutationobserver-shim) *before* `TrixEdit.vue`, and stub `window.getSelection` (called by `trix` and currently not supported by JSDOM):

```js
import 'mutationobserver-shim' // <-- order important
import TrixEdit from '@/components/TrixEdit.vue'

window.getSelection = () => ({})
```

**Solution 2:** Do the above in a Jest setup script, configured by [`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/23.x/configuration#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string):

1. Add the following property to the config object in `jest.config.js` (or `jest` in package.json):

```js
setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/jest-setup.js',
```

2. Add the following code to `<rootDir>/jest-setup.js`:

```js
import 'mutationobserver-shim'
window.getSelection = () => ({})
```

#### Missing `attachToDocument`

`@vue/test-utils` does not attach elements to the document by default, so `trix-editor` does not catch the `connectedCallback`, which is needed for its initialization.

**Solution:** Use the [`attachToDocument` option](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument) when mounting `TrixEdit`:

```js
const wrapper = mount(TrixEdit, {
  //...
  attachToDocument: true, // <-- needed for trix-editor
})
```

#### Premature reference to `trix-editor`'s editor

`TrixEdit` incorrectly assumes that `trix-editor` is immediately initialized upon mounting, but initialization isn't guaranteed until it fires the `trix-initialize` event, so accessing `trix-editor`'s internal editor could result in an `undefined` reference.

**Solution:** Add an [event handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) for the `trix-initialize` event that invokes the initialization code previously in `mounted()`:

```html
<template>
  <trix-editor @trix-initialize="onInit" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onInit(e) {
      /* initialization code */
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Value set before change listener

The initialization code adds a `trix-change`-event listener *after* the value has already been set, missing the event trigger. I assume the intention was to also detect the first initial value setting in order to re-emit it as an `input` event.

**Solution 1:** Add event listener first:

```html
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onInit(e) {
      //...
      el.addEventListener('trix-change', /*...*/)

      /* set editor value */
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Solution 2:** Use `v-on:trix-change="..."` (or `@trix-change`) in the template, which would remove the setup-order problem above:

```html
<template>
  <trix-editor @trix-change="onChange" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.innerHTML)
    },
    onInit(e) {
      //...
      /* set editor value */
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Value setting causes error

The initialization code sets the editor's value with the following code, which causes an error in test:

```js
el.editor.insertHTML(this.value) // causes `document.createRange is not a function`
```

**Solution:** Use `trix-editor`'s `value`-accessor, which performs the equivalent action while avoiding this error:

```js
el.value = this.value
```

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the problem lies in the not-so-ideal polymer polyfill included inside `trix` lib. I did an experiment to force apply the polyfill, then I can reproduce the same error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined` even inside chrome browser env.

Further investigation narrows it down to the `MutationObserver` behavior difference, but still haven't got to the bottom.

Way to reproduce:

**TrixEdit.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div ref="trix">
    <trix-editor></trix-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

// force apply polymer polyfill
delete window.customElements;
document.registerElement = undefined;

import "trix";

//...

</script>
```

Comment: That _is_ pretty gross, but I'll test it on Monday and award the bounty if it all works.

Comment: worth noting, there is a `trix-initialize` event that might work on mount instead of needing a setTimeout

Comment: yeah it's quite gross... But I'm not interested to look any further, will need to look through too much source code

Comment: @Soviut But let me make an educated guess, the difference might root in `@vue/test-utils`. `mounted` lifecycle hook in real app is likely async. But from the way `const wrapper = mount()` is used in test, it looks like the hook is call synchronously.

Comment: @Soviut i can't help digging deeper...here's the latest result i got so far. My guess was wrong. The problem is sourced from `trix` lib. It uses WebComponent `window.customElements` API. When in jsdom env, the API is missing so the polymer polyfill is applied, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Omg, i spent way too much time on this issue. Still can't nail it...this env diff problem is monstrous. I think you should opt to use puppeteer+jest setup to test it in a real browser env. jsdom isn't up for this task.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how `vue-trix` managed to do it https://github.com/hanhdt/vue-trix/blob/master/tests/unit/VueTrix.spec.js maybe the lack of check for the toolbar is why?

Comment: @Soviut The only Vue-Trix test that relies on `trix-editor` behavior is [verifying the `trix-editor`'s `role`](https://github.com/hanhdt/vue-trix/blob/master/tests/unit/VueTrix.spec.js#L77), which is initialized when the element is [created](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/blob/master/src/trix/elements/trix_editor_element.coffee#L165) (not mounted). The majority of the tests focus on Vue-Trix's own functionality.